How to add subtasks to an existing issue through Jira REST API?
I'm trying to add a subtask to an existing issue on my development environment. But I'm not succeeding on it.
Here is my function:
const getID = async (projectId) => {
    const res = await requestJira(
      `/rest/api/3/issuetype/project?projectId=${projectId}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    const taskId = foundIdTask(data);
    return taskId;
  };

  const createSubtasks = async () => {
    const parentIssueKey = context.extension.issue.key;
    const parentIssueId = context.extension.issue.id;
    const projectId = context.extension.project.id;
    const issueType = await getID(projectId); 
  
    if (!issueType) {
      console.error("No valid subtask issue type found.");
      return;
    }
  
    const requestBody = {
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "id": projectId
        },
        "parent": {
          "id": parentIssueId 
        },
        "summary": "Subtask Example",
        "description": {
          "type": "doc",
          "version": 1,
          "content": [{
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [{
              "text": "This is a detailed description of the subtask.",
              "type": "text"
            }]
          }]
        },
        "issuetype": {
          "id": issueType
        }
      }
    };
  
    const response = await requestJira(`/rest/api/3/issue/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    });
  
    if (response.status === 201) {
      console.log("Subtask created successfully!");
    } else {
      console.error("Failed to create subtask:", await response.text());
    }
  };

And I'm getting this error message: Failed to create subtask: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"parentId":"Given parent issue does not belong to appropriate hierarchy."}}
And I don't know what else to do because I'm getting the actual key and id of the issue that I want to work on. And I can add subtasks to this issue with no problem by using the Jira software.
Can someone help me?
Thanks
I've also tried the route "bulk" but I think my request body is not correct, but I can't get it correctly.
